# How to select watch able to sustain sprinting and heavy sporty usage 24/7?

Tags: equipment, running

I have broken far too many watches: their knobs, their hinges, their internal metallic support, scratched the glass, etc. I have scaled back to very cheap watches because so fed up to breaking expensive ones let them be any sport thing such as Suunto, Polar or any normal watch. I want to wear my watch everywhere such as sauna, asleep, school and work. Sauna infers material of low heat conductance such as stainless-steel or titanium. Asleep infers screw-style strengthening of the knob not to get open/broken during sleeping. Running infers strong mechanical features and still needs to be lightweight. 24/7 infers it needs to look great, two time-zones for traveling could be great. There are probably many other things such as interval-training and timing to consider. For now, I am trying to find ways to find a watch that is able to last even at the first place. I may need many watches but for simplicity:

*How should you select a watch that you want to wear 24/7 during **sport**, shower and daily life? Which features do you think are the key things to sustain the 24/7 usage? Does there exist any bionic watch attach to the skin so the watch would not stuck to anything like rocks while climbing?*

Comment: +1 Very nice way of transforming a [product recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) into a useful question.

Comment: With your reference to rock climbing, you may be able to find something on [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not much of a watch guy myself, but after a quick search I found a site that offers many different watch styles. Then I figured that there are many many "rough" watches out there (G-Shock, Rolex, Victorinox, essentially all army & diving watches). So the difficult part is to find something "heat resistant". The watch material thus should be ceramic. After searching a little more I eventually found this one:
http://www.tourneau.com/shop/featured/ceramics/steel-and-ceramic-big-bang-automatic-53879p
Looks kind of indestructible to me. The other one I really like (stylewise as well) is:
http://www.tourneau.com/shop/featured/ceramics#pdpSeoKey!shop_featured_ceramics_aviation-military-ceramic-635p
Its disadvantage though is, that it has a rubber band. Personally I find that rubber wrist bands can become quite uncomfortable after a while, also they wear out much quicker.

They are both really expensive, but as you did not specify a budget I just ignored that factor...

And another thing: I do not know what you mean by "climbing rocks" but if you are doing sports climbing on an upper level you should not wear a watch as the wrist band will lift your hand further away from the rock while holding slopers, thus having less friction on the hold...

Comment: Also possible not to have at all the container like [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=635916436441633), this would avoid getting the watch stuck to all kind of things -- common way to destroy/lose watches.